# NSMutableArray and addObject - Sublist

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

How can I have sub lists using `NSMutableArray` and `addObject`:

Here is the current code:

---

```
categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[categories addObject:@"Line 1"];
[categories addObject:@"Line 2"];
[categories addObject:@"Line 3"];
[categories addObject:@"Line 4"];
```

---

I would like to have sublisting like so:

Line 1

- Line A
- Line B
- Line C

Line 2

- Line A
- Line B
- Line C

...etc...

Let me know if this is possible and how. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're just adding strings to an array. If you want a list within a list, you have to create the sublist and then add it as an object within the main list

```
NSMutableArray *mainList = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *subList = @[@"thing 1",@"thing 2",@"thing 3"];

[mainList addObject:subList];
```

Then, if you want to access and individual subArray, you could do so like this:

```
NSArray *subList = mainList[0];
```

Or an individual sublist item:

```
NSString *item = mainList[0][1];
```

Which would be the second item in the first sublist.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Are you able to take my code to show me with the sublist?

categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[categories addObject:@"Line 1"];
[categories addObject:@"Line 2"];
[categories addObject:@"Line 3"];

Comment: @dmatrixs all you have to do is create your sub arrays (as you can see above with the variable `subList`) and add it to your `categories` array, the same way you're currently adding the strings.

Comment: Downvoter - Is there something wrong with my post that I can correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object, let's say MyObject, which contains a string and another Array

```
@interface MyObject
@property NSString *name;
@property NSMutableArray *items;
@end
```

and add MyObject objects to your categories array.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I daresay you were down voted because your answer makes it sound like a custom object is the only way to go, and it's a solution that's pretty different than what the OP was asking for. The other answer of creating an array within an array was closer to what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I do not agree... An array with another array does not allow to give each object a 'Title' ("Line 1", "Line 2",...) as the user requested. A custom object or an NSDictionary allows you to do that.

Comment: @DuncanC And I never said it was the only way to go. In either case, a downvote is for a not-useful solution, mine is a valid solution. Thanks for your feedback though!

Comment: you said "You need to create an object..." That wording implies that this is the only option. Better to say "One way to do this would be..." Perhaps that's what the person who down-voted you objected to.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
    NSMutableArray *categories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *LineOne = @[@"Line A",@"Line B",@"Line C"];
    NSArray *LineTwo = @[@"Line A",@"Line B",@"Line C"];
    [categories addObject:LineOne];
    [categories addObject:LineTwo];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like NSMutableDictionary is your solution:

```
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

NSArray *line1list, *line2list, *line3list;
// init list arrays

[dict setObject:line1list forKey:@"Line 1"];
[dict setObject:line2list forKey:@"Line 2"];
[dict setObject:line3list forKey:@"Line 3"];
```